# Problem with StaleElementReferenceException error pops up occasionally

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hi I have this code which is generating me:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: 
>   Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

What can be the root cause for it? This code works ok in 10 cases but in 11 not. Is there any chance to improve it to prevent such errors?

Lines which generates the fails are:

```
compare_announcement_text(context, option_name, element_offer_type)
```

And:

```
if element_offer_type.text == option_name:
```

```
def select_announcement(context, option_name):
    """Select announcement from 'Offer Type' drop down
            :param context:
            :param option_name:
            :return: Announcement page
        """
    offer_type = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locators.offer_type)
    offer_type.click()
    offer_type_list = context.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(Locators.all_elements_buttons_offer_type)
    offer_type_text = []
    for element_offer_type in offer_type_list:
        compare_announcement_text(context, option_name, element_offer_type)
        offer_type_text.append(element_offer_type.text)
    if option_name not in offer_type_text:
        time.sleep(0.5)  # menu not fully rendered - need to wait
        offer_type_list = context.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(Locators.all_elements_buttons_offer_type)
        for element_offer_type in offer_type_list:
            compare_announcement_text(context, option_name, element_offer_type)
    from features.pages.announcement_page import AnnouncementPage
    return AnnouncementPage(context)


def compare_announcement_text(context, option_name, element_offer_type):
    if element_offer_type.text == option_name:
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, Locators.all_elements_buttons_offer_type)))
        for check in range(4):
            try:
                ActionChains(context.driver).move_to_element(element_offer_type).click(element_offer_type).perform()
                return
            except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print(f"Tried click {option_name} for 2 seconds - making final click")
            ActionChains(context.driver).move_to_element(element_offer_type).click(element_offer_type).perform()
    else:
        print(f'Element selected in offer type is not {option_name} and is {element_offer_type.text}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easily cause this problem if you use find_elements_by_xpath to get a set of elements first.

I suggest you find element again in for loop like this:

```
offer_type_list = context.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(Locators.all_elements_buttons_offer_type) 
offer_type_text = []
for i in range(1, len(offer_type_list)+1):
    # xpath example: (//div[@class='abc'])[1]
    element_offer_type = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("("+Locators.all_elements_buttons_offer_type+")["+str(i)+"]")
    compare_announcement_text(context, option_name, element_offer_type)
    offer_type_text.append(element_offer_type.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same exception a time ago. Its caused because the element you are interacting is not loaded in the DOM at that moment. You can solve it with a webDriverWait waiting for the element to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonx -> It's not the only reason. Question is also about app, @ranger is using. If it's dynamic (with reloading elements e.g. cause new live data) it's also raises this issue. depending on time when data comes in (e.g. after getting reference to element but before performing action). This can be pain in the ass -,-

@Yun - like this idea, but also (if in testing), using Page Object Pattern, good idea is to use views, and then perform actions within try-except blocks, or actually defining Page elements as property methods, so You'll get clean code, and WebDriver will look for element each time call. That eases up issue.

Yeah, I know that this is not so "well-performance" solution, but - as always - trade offs for stable behaviour with live-dynamic apps.