# How to fix "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying got automate a task via Selenium python i have the issue where the for each section does work only the first time, after that does not see the second variable. Also tried to add delays so the webpage would be fully loaded but the same issue.

I tested different scenarios that i found in the internet also so manual tests i did, but looks like the second  div is not recognizable also the rest of the divs

```
for server in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'server-list-')]"):
  #try:
  print("Server Section----")
  time.sleep(5)
  #Print server name
  print(server.text)

  #clicn on button inside the server
  server.click()

  #back into the server listing
  browser.back()
```

Basically the automation need to enter every server ( div starting with  id server-list- ) click on it, after entering on that section click another button and than back to the main page.

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446398/problem-with-staleelementreferenceexception-error-pops-up-occasionally/58446605#58446605

Answer (score 0):

A stale element reference exception is thrown because of below reason

1. element has been deleted entirely.
2. element is no longer attached to the DOM.

Please check your element is still present on UI with the same element XPath which you are using while interacting with it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'server-list-')]"))
    )           
    for i in range(len(element)):
    element[i].click()
    driver.back()
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'server-list-')]")))

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

With limited information provided, you can try code below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
servers = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'server-list-')]")))
servers_count = len(servers)
for i in range(servers_count):
    print(servers[i].text)
    servers[i].click()
    browser.back()
    servers = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id,'server-list-')]")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You capture the server list that **no more exists after you have drilled into the particular list item**. So when you **get back to the list that old one does not exist any more hence all the items (including that one you expect to move next to) are stale**.

You need to rework your logic so that you get the list of servers each time you get back from the server details and store somethere the flag that would let your script know which items you have already visited.

Comment: If i may ask any suggestion?

Comment: That was the general suggestion in my answer. More detailed answer requires more detailed question. Like for example what is the html snippet that represents your server list